# EC2 instance reboots automatically

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have couple of  t2.large instances which are running on windows server 2008 32bit, the instance reboots automatically every 10minutes. how do i troubleshoot this issue, please guide me

Comment: Have you been able to look in the Windows logs to discover the cause of the reboot? Something must be triggering the reboot, either from within the instance or as an API call to AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Well sometimes its hard to find the solution for the problem like this as it can be a complete hardware problem that you don't have a control over it.

You can either move your instances to a new one or contact [AWS support](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home) for detailed troubleshooting with your instances. They might able to solve this or be able to tell you the cause for it.